# Rollback auto-generated table values during unit tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, hsqldb, dbunit

My unit test config is: JUnit, DBUnit, Spring.

In my Spring context I have an embedded database - [hsqldb](/questions/tagged/hsqldb)

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSourceSpied">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test_ddl.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

My unit tests come with the following class-level annotations:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/test-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
```

My test schema has following fragments:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id  BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  name  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

The `@Transactional` annotation rollbacks any changes I make during a single unit test method **but** doesn't clear the `id` values! The auto-generated `id` value doesn't reset, so the unit tests have a dependency on the order in which they are run!

How to reset auto-generated db fields of HSQLDB in Spring during tests?

---

Perhaps a `trucate` command would help?

Comment: Can't you just ignore the id values in your test?

Comment: I want to check if foreign keys are set properly, and those foregin keys refer to auto-generated `id`

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the autogenerated IDENTITY can be modified.

```
 ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH 0
```

See the guide:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_table_manupulation

Comment: Nice idea, can you provide an example how to integrate it with Spring/JUnit?

Comment: No. Find out how to run this statement before or after each test.

Comment: It's not `@After` simple. DBUnit tests database states after `@After`, lol.